# ASP.NET Javascript Zip Code Lookup for CIty and State w/ Mootools, jQuery, or Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, mootools

I'm trying to write a Javascript Zip Code lookup utility.

1) The User will select a State from a drop down.

2) The City Drown Down will then be populated based on the State selected

3) A textbox below is then populated with the corresponding Zip Code(s) based on Selected State and Zip Code on an ASP.NET page.

Problem:  I get the error Request() is not defined which causes the application to hault when a State is selected.

What should I cahnge in the following code?

```
  <script language="javascript">
   var request = new Request();
   var url = "";

   function getZipCode()
   {    
request.GetNoCache(url + "getZipCode.aspx?City=" +document.getElementById("drpCity").options[document.getElementById("drpCity").selectedIndex].value+ "&State=" +document.getElementById("drpStateSearch").options[document.getElementById("drpStateSearch").selectedIndex].value,      
function(result)
{
    if (result.readyState!=ReadyState.Complete)
        return;             
    if (result.status==HttpStatus.OK && result.responseText != "")
    {
        var zip = result.responseText;
        document.getElementById("txtZip").value = zip;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("txtZip").value = "No Zip Found";
    }
}
)
  }



   function selectCity()
   {    
request.GetNoCache(url + "getCities.aspx?State=" +document.getElementById("drpStateSearch").options[document.getElementById("drpStateSearch").selectedIndex].value,         

function(result)
{

    if (result.readyState!=ReadyState.Complete)
        return;             
    if (result.status==HttpStatus.OK && result.responseText != "")
    {
        var cities = result.responseText;
        var city_array=cities.split(",");
        var len = document.getElementById("drpCity").options.length;

        for( var j=len; j>=0;j--)
        {
            document.getElementById("drpCity").options[j]=null;
        }

        var option_i = new Option("--Select--","--Select--");
        document.getElementById("drpCity").options[0] = option_i;

        for(var i=1; i<=city_array.length-1;i++)
        {
            var option_c = new Option(city_array[i-1],city_array[i-1]);
            document.getElementById("drpCity").options[i] = option_c;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var option_c = new Option("No City","");
        document.getElementById("drpCity").options[0] = option_c;
    }
}
)
   }

            </script>
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   <!--
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    var theform;
    if (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("microsoft") > -1) {
        theform = document.Form2;
    }
    else {
        theform = document.forms["Form2"];
    }
    theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget.split("$").join(":");
    theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theform.submit();
}
   // -->
   </script>

            City: <select id="drpStateSearch" name="drpStateSearch" 
                onchange="Javascript:selectCity();" style="width: 120px;">
                <option value="">---Select---</option>
                <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
                <option value="CA">California</option>
                <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
                <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="ME">Maine</option>
                <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MT">Montana</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                <option value="NY">New York</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="UT">Utah</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
                <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select> <br />
            State: <select id="drpCity" name="drpCity" onchange="javascript:getZipCode()">
                <option selected="">Select State to Populate</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <table id="Table6" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td height="28" width="38%">
                        Zipcode:</td>
                    <td height="28" width="62%">
                        <input id="txtZip" name="txtZip" type="text" /></td>
```

Thanks!

Comment: In what way is this code not working the way you expect it to?

Comment: @striplingWarrior, Thanks for your response. The Problem/Error has been added to the question. Please check it now.  Problem: I get the error Request() is not defined which causes the application to hault when a State is selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using MooTools? If so you need to make certain the mootools lib is brought in before you attempt to make a new Request object. If not Request isn't the proper object to create for an ajax request.

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
   request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else if(window.ActiveXObject)
{
   request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.onreadystatechange = callback;
request.send(null);
function callback()
{
   if(request.readyState == 4)
   {
       if(request.status == 200)
       {
             /* do your call back stuff here */
       }
    }
 }
```

Note is is really basic and kind of a pain and I would suggest using a framework lib such as jQuery or Mootools to do ajax calls to your server code.

/************** UPDATE ***********************************/
Here is the code for a basic Jquery ajax request:

```
$.ajax({ url: "test.html", 
         context: document.body, 
         data:{"info":"I'm sending this back to the server"}, 
         success: function(data){ 
              /* do your callback stuff here */ 
         },
         error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              /* let's you know where you went wrong */
         }
});
```

The api def is [here.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you provide the code for doing it with jQuery as well? Mootools can be downloaded here: http://mootools.net/download

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(data){
    /* do your callback stuff here */
  }
});. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you edit your answer to add that code to help other people out?

Comment: how would this code be adapted for populating a listbox full of zip codes, zipcodelistbox, from state_zip database table based on the state selected from a statedropdownllist?

Comment: The success handler receives data back from the server (a json structure would probably be the simplest or you can send back straight html). Then within that function you either fill the list box or replace the list box (depending on what you send from the server).